# Converting data frame into numeric sparseMatrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a `data.frame` with 3 columns. The structure of the `data.fame` is as below

> str(data)
> 'data.frame':   76971772 obs. of  3 variables:
> $ V1: chr  "XH104_AACGAGAGCTAAACTAGCCCTA" "XH104_AACGAGAGCTAAACTAGCCCTA" "XH104_AACGAGAGCTAAACTAGCCCTA" "XH104_AACGAGAGCTAAACTAGCCCTA" ...
> $ V2: chr  "10:100175000-100180000" "10:101065000-101070000" "10:101550000-101555000" "10:101585000-101590000" ...
> $ V3: int  2 2 2 2 10 1 2 2 2 2 ...

I am trying to convert it into `sparseMatrix` such that the row name of `sparseMatrix` is `data$V1` and the column name is `data$V2`. I am using the command given below to do that.

```
sparse.data <- with(data, sparseMatrix(i=as.numeric(V1), j=as.numeric(V2), x=V3, dimnames=list(levels(V1), levels(V2))))
```

I keep getting the this error.

```
Error in sparseMatrix(i = as.numeric(V1), j = as.numeric(V2), x = V3,  : 
  NA's in (i,j) are not allowed
```

I realized that when I use `i=as.numeric(V1)` in my command, all the values of V1 become `NA`.

Can someone suggest how can I solve this error?

Comment: `V1` and `V2` need to be factors, not character vectors, for this to work.  See `?factor`.

Comment: I tired to convert V1 and V2 as.factor and then as.numeric but that does not retain the actual barcode value as it is in original data.frame(data). Can you give an example as to how I should load it.

Comment: You're better off fixing this problem before you turn it into a data frame. Looks a lot like something you loaded from a matrixmarket file.

Comment: @CJR do you have some suggestion how can I do that?